# PHP function to Calculate Excel worksheet no of rows which has data

Tags: php

I am using PHPExcel where following line of command gives full data Range.

```
echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDataDimension()
```

**Outputs:**

> A1:XFD153

But i need only the number of rows, i.e **153** for above case.

Is there any inbuilt function to get number of excel rows which has data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want...

```
echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
```

Comment: No problem. Found it in a thread [here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/234556).